# How to shrink colorbar of heatmap()?

Tags: plots.jl

Code below produced too large colorbar compared to the heatmap itself. I didn't find a way to shrink the color bar. See the image: [too large colorbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbJpu.png)

```
heatmap(z,aspect_ratio=1)
plot!(colorbar=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer elsewhere:
Colorbars are handled by the backend, so you cannot control that at the moment within Plots.jl.
Work-arround: change size of plot frame to match size of colorbar by for instance:

```
pyplot(size=(3000,900)
```